# debug this code? alerts not working?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong, my alerts are not coming up when i try submit the form without filling in required fields.

When I just include the one alert script for "name" field it will work, I have tried adding more parameters such as email phone and name into the one validation script but that doesnt seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateName() {
var x = document.forms["form"]["Name"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
alert("your name needs to be entered");
return false;
}
} 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
function validateEmail() {
var x = document.forms["form"]["Email"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
alert("your email needs to be entered");
return false;
}
}  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function validatePhone() {
var x = document.forms["form"]["Phone"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
alert("your phone number needs to be entered");
return false;
}
}  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validateComments() {
var x = document.forms["form"]["comments"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
alert("please enter some comments");
return false;
}
}  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateMail(email) {
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|  (".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-  Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
}
</script>


<form action="formmail.php" method="get" name= "form"     onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<p> name </p>
<input type="text" name="Name" min="2"/>
<br>  
<p>email</p>
<input type="email" name="Email" min="2"/>
<br>   
<p> phone number</p>
<input type="tel" name="Phone"/>
<br>

<h2> Team </h2>
<p>Select your team<br/>
</p>
<select multiple name="interests">
<option value="Adults">Adults</option>
<option value="Under12s" >Under 12s</option>
<option value="under6s" >Under 6s</option>
</select>
<h2>Are you an existing member? </h2>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="roomRating" value="excellent">yes<br/>
<input type="radio" name="roomRating" value="good">no<br/>
</p>
<p> comments </p>
<textarea name="comments" rows="5" cols="25" id="comments">   </textarea>
<p>
<input onclick="myFunction" type="submit" name="submit"    value="Submit"/>
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: don't use same function names

Comment: ah so simple thankyou

Comment: Just changed the function names and alerts still not working :(

Comment: can you update the post with new codes

Comment: you don't need use script tag put every function.just one script tag and multiple functions

Comment: in updated code you only call `validateForm` method.

Comment: okk I have removed the un needed script tags , I don't really know what you mean by that I am only calling the validateForm method, how do i call all of them?

Comment: i created a validate function which calls for all validate functions.for simplicity i only include phone and name functions.here is the jsbin url http://output.jsbin.com/hikuzuvuji

Comment: oh sweet thanks very much I shall tinker

Comment: also in your validation function return true is missing.add it like in my example

Comment: @MathewBowyer Here is a better all-encompassing function. You should really check if they have chosen a radio button though http://jsbin.com/qonusotayo/edit?js,output

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have more than one function with the same name `validateForm`, only the last one will persist. You can combine them to a single function but, with your current approach, only the first alert will be produced. That is, only the first error will be indicated.

Comment: hmmm I just tried that and it didn't work? just submits without any alert

Comment: I cannot comment on code I cannot see. You should probably open a new question now that you've rewritten the code.

Comment: @sosro: Mark this answer as correct answer if this is the appropriate answer.